# Regex Python sacar datos de un txt

Tags: python, regex

*Tengo el siguiente regex:*

```
[0-9]{8}(?::)[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+(?::)+[A-Z]{1}+[a-z]+(?::)+[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+(?::)
```

*Resultado:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que sacar datos de un txt con este formato
(DNI 8 digitos:Nombre1:Nombre2:Apellido1:Apellido2 o DNI 8 digitos:Nombre1::Apellido1:Apellido2), y he pensado en hacerlo con un parametro con regex.

Comment: No está clara tu pregunta. Tienes un regex que parece estar bueno, unos datos que parecen ser de entrada. ¿Donde estas parado?

Comment: La captura es de una pagina con la que hago la prueba de regex.

Comment: Creo que me he explicado mal.
Lo que me refiero es que tengo que comprobar el formato de los datos.
Y se me ha ocurrido hacerlo con regex.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que los datos están separados con un `:` y cuando no hay datos hay un `::` puedes separarlos directamente con un `split()` y asumir que columna es cada índice de la lista retornada.

Algo como lo siguiente:

```
text = "12345678:César::Mora"
splited= text.split(":")

dni = splited[0]
first_name = splited[1]
second_name = splited[2]
family_name = splited[3]

print("dni: ", dni)
print("first_name: ", first_name)
print("second_name: ", second_name)
print("family_name: ", family_name)
```

Comment: Y como son nombres, podemos asumir que no contendran un ":".

Answer (score -1):

Este es el regex que me funciona

```
"[0-9]{8}(?::)[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+(?::)((?::)|[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+(?::))[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+(?::)[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+"
```